# How to create multiple columns using data from the filter function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I just started using google sheets to help edit tables for a database and I need some help creating a function. In ColumnA, I've got a list of MovieID's, in ColumnB, there is a list of directors, and in ColumnC, there is a list of unique directors from ColumnB. I'm trying to filter the data and create a set of columns where in one, there is the director's name and in the other, there's the movieID that corresponds to a film the director was involved in.

Ive created a function in F2 to find the ids for a director, and I can just drag the formula down (when the data is transposed, and the C2 value will shift to C3, C4....) But, I want the name of the director to be included in the column to the left of the filtered results (like I've manually done in E), but I can't really figure it out, and I'm not entirely sure on how to use the other functions to get it right.

Any help or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!!
[image]

Comment: Are you going to want this E:F list for just one director at a time? Or are you going to want a complete list of all directors and all the movie IDs, grouped by director? Also, what is the maximum number of directors for any one film in your list?

Comment: @ErikTyler the latter; movie ids grouped by director

Comment: I just added a question to my comment above.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you provided the starting point directly by sharing a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it) here. Just be sure, when creating the link, to set the permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor" so that it can be accessed.

Comment: @ErikTyler The maximum is around 6, but most will probably have around 2 or 3 each

Comment: @ErikTyler I actually found a really roundabout way of doing this about an hour ago, but it takes some time for the function to work out for each cell, and there around 16,000 rows. I was gonna post my solution in the morning

Comment: OK, sounds like you're saying you are all set then.

Comment: @ErikTyler Yes, thank you for your reply though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this will solve your issue

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
                        SPLIT(B2:B,", ",0)&"@"&A2:A),"@"),
                  " where Col2 is not null order by Col1 "))
```

If on the other hand there is only one name in cell `E2` use

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B,E2),C2&"-"&A2:A,),"-"))),
           "where Col1 is not null",0)
```